# No results on combobox C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I am trying to populate my combo box with the data from my database but my problem is that, this code that I have here is error free and I've tweak things out of it. but the problem is that whenever I run the code, there will be no results placed on the combo box.

What seems to be the problem here?

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=H:/hellhole/combobox/combobox/rooms.sdf");
connection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select room from database.rooms", connection);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet data = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(data);


comboBox1.DataSource = data.Tables[0];
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "room";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "room";
comboBox1.Enabled = true;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Not to be totally obvious, but is there any actual *data* in that table?

Comment: Yes, I have placed data on my table

Comment: I've tried what you've recommend but still gives me no results.

Comment: try `DataBind()` as below mentioned

Answer (score 0):

remove ExecuteNonQuery(),You don't have to call executeNonQuery because the fill method of the dataadapter is used to populate the results from a select command. Sorry,the DataBind() I have edited my code

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("DataSource=H:/hellhole/combobox/combobox/rooms.sdf");
connection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select room from database.rooms", connection);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet data = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(data);
connection.Close(); 

comboBox1.DataSource = data.Tables[0];
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "room";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "room";
comboBox1.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Tried this one but gives me an error:  'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: Then remove `comboBox1.DataBind();` and retry it.. come one now .. you should be aware of how to debug and test your own code...respectfully speaking..

Comment: @staphpleasehelp: All Visual Studio versions (even Express) have fantastic debuggers. Learn to love the Locals and Watch windows. Also, click on any word in the editor window and press F1 to be taken to the online help for the keyword, type, property, or method.

Comment: @staphpleasehelp:`comboBox1.DataBind();` for webforms..as you did not mentioned if it is winforms or web applications.